# Read data into a circular buffer

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio, circular-buffer

Is it possible to use `boost::circular_buffer` with `boost::asio`?

Specifically I want to read a fixed number of bytes with `boost::asio::async_write` and store them directly in the circular buffer without copying.

Some example code would be very nice!

Comment: yes, you can. Some example code would be nice.

Comment: Look at following members of `circular_buffer`: [`array_one`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#classboost_1_1circular__buffer_1957cccdcb0c4ef7d80a34a990065818d), [`array_two`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#classboost_1_1circular__buffer_1f5081a54afbc2dfc1a7fb20329df7d5b), [`rotate`](http://tinyurl.com/lmg2axt) and [`linearize`](http://tinyurl.com/kv5tddl). You can use `array_one()` and `array_two()` to get internal buffers(slices of one big buffer) and feed `boost::asio::buffer` with them.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyPanasyuk for these hints. I will try on monday if I can get it to work with a mutable buffer sequence consisting of `array_one` and `array_two`.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's an acceptable answer for this one.

Comment: Hi @RobertHegner did you ever get this figured out

Comment: You sure you want to *read* using `async_write`?

Answer (score 2):

As of right now (Boost 1.66), it is not possible to **read** data into `boost::circular_buffer` because it doesn't expose any way to reserve space in the underlying buffer, which is a requirement for creating a `mutable_buffer` needed to call `asio::read`.

But it is possible to **write** from `boost::circular_buffer`:

```
  boost::circular_buffer<char> cir_buf;

  FillBuffer(cir_buf);

  // Construct a buffer sequence with either 1 or 2 data chunks
  std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffer_sequence;

  auto arr1 = cir_buf.array_one();
  buffer_sequence.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(arr1.first, arr1.second));

  auto arr2 = cir_buf.array_two();
  if (arr2.second != 0) {
    buffer_sequence.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(arr2.first, arr2.second));
  }

  boost::asio::write(socket_, buffer_sequence);
```